# I want to refetch data from an api in an interval of time using componentWillUnmount clearTime and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

refetching data without reloading the page in an interval of time

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    taskExecutions: null,
    total: null,
    per_page: null,
    current_page: 0
  };
  this.intervalID = 5000;
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.makeHttpRequestWithPage(0, 4);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearTimeout(this.intervalID);
}

makeHttpRequestWithPage = async(pageNumber, sizePerPage) => {
  if (sizePerPage <= 0) {
    sizePerPage = this.state.per_page;
  }
  fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/taskExecution? 
                        page=${pageNumber}&size=${sizePerPage}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        taskExecutions: data.content,
        total: data.totalPages,
        per_page: data.size,
        current_page: data.number
      });
      this.intervalID = setTimeout(this.makeHttpRequestWithPage(this.state.current_page, this.state.per_page).bind(this), 8000);
    });
}
render() { /*..*/ }
```

I get the data from the api but after 8 seconds I got this ERROR :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.makeHttpRequestWithPage(...).bind is not a function

I expect the data to be refreshed automatically after 8 seconds

Comment: You're calling `.bind` on the return value of `this.makeHttpRequestWithPage` and that function doesn't return anything. In any case, you don't need bind for this because you've defined `makeHttpRequestWithPage` as an arrow function.

Comment: i'hv deleted the .bind(this) but i got an infinite loop with the following LOG :

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier setTimeout (async)  
(anonymous) Promise.then (async)  
TaskExecutionList.makeHttpRequestWithPage 
(anonymous)

Comment: Use, `....setTimeout(() => this.makeHttpRequestWithPage(this.state.current_page,this.state.per_page)` or `....setTimeout(this.makeHttpRequestWithPage.bind(this, this.state.current_page,this.state.per_page)`